# Why I get a red exclamation in android studio when I try to use setBackgroundResource?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

When I try to change the background of my button with

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_orange);
```

I get a red exclamation in Line numbers , is it because the minimum sdk version is 15?  should someone worry? What should I do for that?

Comment: what does the error say? `setBackgroundResource` has been introduced in api `1` so it shouldn't conflict with `minSdk` 15

Comment: Does not say anything , it is just there in the line numbers

Comment: That is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you are talking about this **!** mark,  then it is just like a link which will show you ***button.orange*** from drawable.